# is it possible to edit .resx after deployment by setting Build action to Embedded Resource

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, embedded-resource

I am using asp.net core application and in my application Resources.resx file properties Build Action is set to Embedded Resource and Copy to output directory is set to copy always and from my virtual directory i am editing that file but changes are not getting reflected.

Is there any way to get this done?